# password_verify() how does it work with same password?

Tags: php, password-hash, php-password-hash

I'm wondering, if two users in the database have the same password, the `password_hash()` will create two different hashes, is that right? And if so, how does it do it?
And how does it work with `password_verify()` when there are two passwords that are equally the same. I'm trying to understand the works behind this one.

Comment: You can check this yourself - hash a password and run it twice, see what it outputs.

Comment: Yes, I know what the output is. I want to know how the function generates different hashes when it's the same password with two different users.

Comment: The difference is created because salt is used. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: @ChrisHaas so if I understand correctly, each salt is different with every user even if it's the same password?

Comment: There is a lot more information in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords.

Comment: Yes, it is randomly generated and you can even see the salt in the password string itself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use PHP's password\_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords)